# Sending template email with nodemailer, broken styles

Tags: html, handlebars.js, nodemailer, express-handlebars

trying to send a template email using nodemailer and making the template with handlebars.

The email does send but the styling of the email is not right. It looks like this

[image]

I have attached what I've written in my handlebars template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Welcome to</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin');
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; left: 0; top: 0; background-color: white; }
        h1 { font-family: 'Cabin'; font-weight: 600; color: rgba(5,45,84,1); margin-left: 2px;}
        p { font-family: 'Cabin'; font-weight: 400; font-size: 11pt; color: rgba(5,45,84,1); margin-left: 2px; }
        h3 {
            margin-top: 50px;
            color: rgba(5,45,84,.25);
            font-family: 'Cabin'; 
            font-weight: 400; 
            font-size: 10pt;
            width: 80vw;
        }
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 25px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            color: rgba(5,45,84,1);
            font-family: 'Cabin'; 
            font-weight: 400; 
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        h3 > a { color: rgba(118,146,255,1); }
        h3 > a:hover { cursor: pointer; }
        h3 > a:active { opacity: .75; }
        .page-container { width: 80vw; margin-left: 10vw; }
        .logo { margin-left: 2px; height: 30px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; }
        .divider { height: 1px; width: 100%; background-color: rgba(5,45,84,.1); margin-bottom: 40px; }
        .button-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            margin-top: 25px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .cta {
            transition: all 200ms; 
            -webkit-transition: all 200ms; 
            -moz-transition: all 200ms; 
            -o-transition: all 200ms;
            -ms-transition: all 200ms;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 46px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 11pt;
            font-family: 'Cabin';
            font-weight: 500;
            padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            background-color: #7692FF;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(118,146,255,.25);
        }
        .cta:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .cta:active {
            margin-top: 4px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px rgba(118,146,255,.25);
        }
        .footer-container {
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            background-color: rgba(5,45,84,.04);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-container">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <h1>Welcome to</h1>
        <p>
            Hi Matthew, thanks for signing up for. We're so happy to have you! almost ready to join your first group. Click the link below to verify your email.
        </p>
        <div class="button-container">
            <div class="cta">
            GET STARTED
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>
            We'll reach out again when we're ready for you to start using. Just reply to this email if you have any questions.
        </p>
        <p>
            - Team Something
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-container">
        <h3 class="footer">
            If you need help, respond to this message. If this message was sent to you by mistake and you did not sign up for an account with us, we apologize.
        </h3>
        <h2>a9 Something 2018</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems to me that there are certain styles that don't apply, the imported font from google, the centering of the word on the button and the box shadow. Does flex work with handlebars??

Answer (score 5):

Email clients are notorious for display issues. It is always recommended to use nested tables, and some basic elements, but mostly tables.

Use inline styling, and keep it as basic as you can. Most of HTML5 won't be fully supported.